# Implementing Piping for C shell project

Tags: c, shell, command, pipe

So I have a project that involves creating a simple shell in C and one of the features is to support piping, e.g., a program like:

./a.out | ./b.out
would redirect the stdout from ./a.out to the stdin of ./b.out

The instructions in my assignment state to use 2 fork() calls, one for each command.

Here is what I have so far... but I have no idea how to use 2 fork calls and what to even do exactly...I would greatly appreciate any tips! Thanks!

```
void doPipe()
{
    // here I have 2 int arrays that will be passed in to pipe(),
    // since pipe takes in an int array of file descriptors to know 
    // where to get input and store output
    int p1[2] = {STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO};
    int p2[2] = {STDIN_FILENO, STDOOUT_FILENO};

    // here i fork to run child process
    pid_t pID = fork();

    if (pID == 0} { do stuff in child; }
    else { do stuff in parent;}
}
```

Comment: There are probably millions of examples of how to do this, all over the Internet. In summary: Read about `pipe`, more about `fork`, `dup2`, and `exec`.

Comment: See: http://tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node11.html